# Set multiple placeholders in nested form fields using an array in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, nested-forms

Using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and [nested_form_fields](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields), I have a page that allows users to add questions. By default we create three empty questions, but there's a button for them to keep adding new fields, so they can add as many questions as they like.

For each field I would like a different placeholder. I figure I can have an array of placeholders which just repeats when it gets to the end. Here's what I have so far.

I define my array as a constant in the `Question` model:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  PLACEHOLDERS = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5']
  ...
end
```

I render the form fields as a loop, one for each question:

```
= f.nested_fields_for :questions do |question|
  = render partial: 'form_fields', locals: { f: question, placeholder: Question::PLACEHOLDERS.first }
```

In the partial, we have the field with the `placeholder` variable passed through.

```
= f.input :body, as: :text, placeholder: placeholder
```

Now obviously this isn't what I want as I am only passing the first placeholder in the array. What I need help with is modifying this so that it will pass through `n` placeholder for `n` question, and loop back to the start when there are more questions than placeholders in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with `haml` syntax.

But you can take a **variable `i` and initialize to `0`**

Now, while looping each question, increment the value of `i` and send to the partial using,  **`Question::PLACEHOLDERS[i]`**

```
- i = 0
= f.nested_fields_for :questions do |question|
  = render partial: 'form_fields', locals: { f: question, placeholder: Question::PLACEHOLDERS[i] }
  - i = i + 1
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. That certainly gets me closer. Now I need to figure out how to keep populating the placeholder as the user adds more fields, which I assume `nested_fields_for` is doing with JS.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate?

Comment: Imagine I have 4 items in the array. When the page is rendered we iterate through the loop three times, rendering three fields, and the first three placeholder strings from the array. I click the `add_nested_fields_link` and it adds another field, with the 4th item in the array. I keep clicking to add more fields, and it doesn't repeat the array, it just keeps adding the fourth. But since there are no page refreshes I assume this is JS.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [nested_form_fields](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields),

> To enable string substitution with the current index use the magic
>   string **__nested_field_for_replace_with_index__**.

So, I guess you can use

```
= f.nested_fields_for :questions do |question|
  = render partial: 'form_fields', locals: { f: question, placeholder: Question::PLACEHOLDERS[__nested_field_for_replace_with_index__] }
```

Comment: Thought you'd struck gold there for a minute but I don't think it's working. ```undefined local variable or method `__nested_field_for_replace_with_index__'```

Comment: Did you try it as a string? From source code I guess they are expecting it as string. I mentioned this because I saw this in the documentation. So I thought you can give it a try :)

Comment: There is a possibility that the array evaluation will be done before it is passed to the gem. So it may not work.

Comment: That just gives me `no implicit conversion of String into Integer` unfortunately.

Comment: Yea I expected that.. There will be some way to use this but i guess we are not using it in the right way

Comment: I opened an issue on the Github repo, let's see if someone gets back there.

Comment: From source code, this can be used only with client side code and not server side code.

Comment: Ah I thought that could have been the case. Hopefully​ they'll update the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The `fields_for` partial is evaluated when the page is rendered, rather than each time the "Add Question" button is clicked.

However, you can use `nested_fields_for`'s `fields_added` callback to update the placeholders using javascript/coffeescript:

**new.html.slim**

```
= simple_form_for @questionnaire do |f|
  = f.input :title

  = f.nested_fields_for :questions do |question|
    = render partial: 'form_fields', locals: { f: question, placeholder: Question::PLACEHOLDERS.first }

  = f.add_nested_fields_link :questions

  javascript:
    var placeholders = #{Question::PLACEHOLDERS.to_json.html_safe}
```

**_form_fields.html.slim**

```
= f.input :body, as: :text, placeholder: placeholder, input_html: { class: 'has-placeholder'}
```

**questionnaires.coffee**

```
$(document).on "fields_added.nested_form_fields", (event, param) ->
  field = $(event.target).find('.has-placeholder')
  $(field).attr('placeholder', placeholders[Math.floor(Math.random()*placeholders.length)]);
```